# Bind json data to kendo grid

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have to bind the Result of a web API(post) call to a kendo grid. The result format is

```
{
  "Id": 121,
  "referenceId": 18222,
  "status": null,
  "message": "Completed"
}
```

API call is :

```
            read: {
                url: //url,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
            },
            parameterMap: function () {
                return JSON.stringify({ Active: false });
            }
        },
        schema: {
           data:'data'
        }
```

Bind :

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({

          dataSource: dataSource
           columns: [{
                        field: "Id",
                        title: "Id"
                    }]
});
```

But its not working. :(

Answer (score 1):

Use kendo.all.min file in reference.

use this dataSource part

```
schema: {
                  model: {
                       id: "Id",
                      fields: {                                      
                          Id: {  },
                          referenceId: { },
                          status: { },
                          message: {} 
                     }
                  }
              }
```

use this at grid side

```
      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: [{
              "Id": 121,
              "referenceId": 18222,
              "status": "test",
              "message": "Completed"
          }],
          navigatable: true,
          pageable: true,
          height: 550,
          toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
          columns: [
               { field: "Id", title: "Unit Price" },
                { field: "referenceId", title: "Units In Stock" },
                { field: "status", width: 120 },
                { field: "message", width: 120 }
          ],
          editable: true
      });
```